# Why doesn't the python dictionary work as i expect it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import sys

def main():
    list_placeholder = [0 for _ in range(1, len(sys.argv))]
    dict_file_content = {}

    for arg_file in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
        content = ''
        with open(sys.argv[arg_file]) as f:
            for line in f:
                content += line
            dict_file_content[arg_file] = content

    dict_symbols = {}

    for key in dict_file_content:
        content = dict_file_content[key]
        for i in content:
            if dict_symbols.get(i) == None:
                dict_symbols[i] = list_placeholder

    for key in dict_file_content:
        content = dict_file_content[key]
        for key_symbol in dict_symbols:
            dict_symbols[key_symbol][key-1] = content.count(key_symbol)
    print(dict_symbols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I need to pass n text files to the program and get the output:

```
{'A': [12, 3], 'm': [8, 15], 'a': [19, 23], 'z': [7, 6], 'i': [5, 4] , ...}
```

where the dictionary key is a unique character, and the list is the number of occurrences of this character in the text, list[0] = the number of occurrences in the first text, list[1] = number of occurrences in the second text, etc.

Comment: What's the input and what's the output you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: ./count.py text1.txt text2.txt

{'A': [0, 2], 'm': [0, 2], 'a': [0, 2], 'z': [0, 2], 'i': [0, 2], 'n': [0, 2], 'g': [0, 2], ',': [0, 2], ' ': [0, 2], 't': [0, 2], 'e': [0, 2], 'r': [0, 2], 'b': [0, 2], 'l': [0, 2], 'h': [0, 2], 'v': [0, 2], 'y': [0, 2], 'd': [0, 2], 's': [0, 2], '.': [0, 2], 'S': [0, 2], 'o': [0, 2], 'k': [0, 2], 'c': [0, 2], 'f': [0, 2], 'G': [0, 2], 'u': [0, 2], 'p': [0, 2], '\n': [0, 2], 'D': [0, 2], 'O': [0, 2], 'U': [0, 2], '1': [0, 2], '9': [0, 2], 'w': [0, 2], 'x': [0, 2], 'I': [0, 2], 'B': [0, 2], '-': [0, 2], 'T': [0, 2], 'E': [0, 2], '2': [0, 2], '0': [0, 2],

Comment: btw, move that comment into the question so that you can format it nicely.

Comment: You can iterate over a dictionary using `.items()`, instead of iterating over the keys and having to get every single value. Don’t compare to `None` with `==`, use `is` instead. It looks like you’re trying to get all the contents of a file into a string. If that’s the case, just do `f.read()`. I’m also confused as to why you start the first `range()` at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dict_symbols` has references to the same list. You need to give each entry its own list:

```
    for key in dict_file_content:
        content = dict_file_content[key]
        for i in content:
            if dict_symbols.get(i) == None:
                dict_symbols[i] = list_placeholder[:]
```

Notice `list_placeholder[:]` make a copy.